# Check to see if a webcam is turned on (mac)

Tags: macos, webcam

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to determine whether or not a webcam is active on OSX. I'm open to a shell command, python, node, applescript or any other method.

I want to run some automation (turn on a lamp) when either my built-in webcam turns on/off, or when my external logitech camera turns on/off.

I've found some solution that claim to work, but don't - or that can only detect the built-in camera.

Comment: Did you have any luck? Im trying to do the same

Comment: No. I finally just automated based on whether a tab was open to meet.google.com

Comment: The problem is I use Skype, Zoom or Google meets, so I cant rely in just one app.. :( but thanks